# Make button disappear after running procedure

Tags: python, button, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a Tkinter window that at the moment has 18 buttons, and they all have the same code:

```
    Button2=Button(master,text='click me',command=lambda:callback())
    Button2.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

when I execute this code it runs the procedure

```
callback
```

but I want it to run the procedure and then disappear; I have tried

```
def hide_me(event):
event.widget.grid_forget()

Button2=Button(master,text='click me',command=lambda:callback())
Button2.bind('<Button-1>',hide_me) 
Button2.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

but when I press the button it makes the button disappear without executing the callback, and when I try:

```
def callback(Buttons):

   C = Characters.pop(0)
   Buttons.bind('<Button-1>',hide_me())
   return C()


Button2=Button(master,text='click me',command=lambda:callback(Button2))
Button2.bind('<Button-1>',hide_me) 
Button2.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

it runs the callback, but the button doesn't disappear. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `bind` if you already use the `command` keyword arg.

Just wrap `callback()` and `grid_forget()` into one method:

```
def callback_and_hide(button):
    callback()
    button.grid_forget()

Button2 = Button(master,text='click me',command=lambda: callback_and_hide(Button2))
```

Comment: I made a slight edit, your version returned errors, you needed to pass the parameter "Button2" to "callback_and_hide()". Also "event.widget.grid_forget" returns and error you just need to use "event.grid_forget()"